# How to push row of two-dimensional array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following array:

```
var myArray = [
[47,22,11],
[28,5,1],
[22,11,11]
]
```

And I need the following structure:

```
  var myStructure = [
    { Pass: 47, Warning: 22,  Fail: 11},
    { Pass: 28, Warning:5,  Fail: 1},
    { Pass: 22, Warning:11, Fail: 11;},
];
```

How can I do that

Comment: This is a *very* straightforward application of `Array#map` and object initializer syntax.

Comment: Sigh. Now we'll _never_ know what the OP tried already :)

Comment: @Andy - Sorry, I figured I could write an answer as quickly as a comment. But I think we can *guess* what the OP tried, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),

```js
var myArray = [
  [47,22,11],
  [28,5,1],
  [22,11,11]
];


var myStructure = myArray.map(function (el) {
  return {
    Pass: el[0],
    Warning: el[1],
    Fail: el[2],
  }
});

console.log(myStructure);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Array `.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var myStructure = myArray.map(function(el) {
                    return { Pass : el[0], Warning : el[1], Fail : el[2] };
                  });
```